# Understanding HttpWebRequest POST request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

So I have a bit of a problem understanding the POST method for C#, I have some REST endpoints to post info about your progression and so on. But looking at the request coming in on the server side there is no body. So I started digging into this, and there must be something fundamental I am missing.

So the request.GetRequestStream().Write(body, 0, body.Length) actually sends out the request to the api endpoint. Do i need to implement something on the backend to handle this behaviour? I have a simple express service running for backend stuff. Because right now my body data is always empty.

```
public async void postTime(String levelID, float time)
{
    try
    {
        String bearer = getBearerTokenFromCtx();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/user/level/{1}/highscore", BASE_PATH, levelID));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";

        WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
        headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
        request.Headers = headers;

        string json = "{\"time\": 0.01}";
        byte[] body = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
        request.ContentLength = body.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(body, 0, body.Length);
        //WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try closing the stream after writing to it?

Comment: Same behaviour with closing the stream

Comment: @mrmjauh please share the code where you close the stream